# Python: как правильно реализовать структуру классов для получения работы как в примере

Tags: python, классы

Есть класс который может неким образом изменять датафрейм:

```
class features:
    def add_feature_1(self, *arg)
        ...
    def add_feature_2(self, *arg)
        ...
    def add_feature_n(self, *arg)
        ...
```

есть класс в котором сохраняются датафреймы которыми в дальнейшем будут пользоваться другие классы:

```
class data:
    df1
    df2
    ...
    dfn
```

и на конец есть класс который ими пользуется:

```
class model:
    ...
    что то делает
```

**Как правильно все связать чтобы получить следующую функциональность в языке python**:

```
m = model()
...
m.df2.add_feature_1(*arg)
...
```

количество датафреймов и их изменения определяется пользователем в зависимость от проводимого эксперимента по ходу дел (то есть их не лзя инициализировать за ранее при m=model() в смысли что не знаешь сколько и какими они будут)

Answer (score 0):

***Мне кажется***, что лучше убрать `class data` и добавить список с датафреймами в `class model` (в таком случае его, вероятно, стоит переименовать в `models`) и обращаться к ним по индексу. Получится примерно следующее:

```
class features:
    def add_feature_1(self, *arg):
        ...
    def add_feature_2(self, *arg):
        ...
    def add_feature_n(self, *arg):
        ...


class models:
    dataframes = []

m = models()
# обращаемся по индексу к первому df в списке и изменяем его с помощью метода класса features
m.dataframes[0] = features.add_feature_2(m.dataframes[0])
```

Comment: Я уже делаю нечто похожие, но хочу избавится от передачи датафрейма так как для пользователя получается слишком длинно и склонно к ошибкам в моделировании эксперимента, хочу получить форму:  m.df2.add_feature_1(*arg)  что бы было быстро и понятно на глаз что делает обработка в конкретном эксперименте и не склонно к ошибкам. Скажем так чтобы пользователь минимально отвлекался на программирование и занимался исключительно экспериментом.

Comment: @Александр Для того, чтобы пользователь не отвлекался на программирование, создают графические интерфейсы. Чтобы получить ту форму, которую вы хотите, сам объект класса `Dataframe` должен иметь медоты `add_feature...`. Я сейчас добавлю еще один ответ

Comment: да, конечно скрыть все в коробку с графическим интерфейсом решило бы много проблем для пользователя но на такое я пока что не могу тратить ресурсы

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 2. Более приближенный к вашей цели. [Наследуется](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/python-oop-basics/lessons/inheritance/theory_unit) класс `Dataframe` в новый нами созданный класс `MyDataframe` в котором мы и пропишем собственные методы

```
class MyDataframe(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyDataframe, self).__init__()

    def add_features_1(self):
        ...

    def add_features_2(self):
        ...

class Models:
    dataframes = [MyDataframe(), MyDataframe()]

m = Models()
m.dataframes[0].add_features_1()
```

Comment: да такое может подойти